# Pushing a view when the rootViewController is not a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, storyboard, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

Alright, so I've been looking around for an answer to the following question: How to push a certain view controller into view when a push notification arrives from the AppDelegate?

And most answers are that if the rootViewController is a UINavigationController, I have to instantiate a view via my StoryBoard and push it with that root navigation controller.

Here's my situation. Here's how my storyboard is organised:

[image]

So as you see my rootViewController doesn't have UINavigationController. So, how do I go about pushing a certain view out of my storyboard?

NOTE: Presenting some separate modal view for push notifications isn't really a great idea. It's my last resort.

I'd like a solution as in the Apple Mail and Message apps.

Comment: You can add embed your rootViewController in navigationController and keep the navigationBar hidden ?

Comment: That's a start, but then how do I push another view from the StoryBoard? Or is it only possible to create and show new ones?

Comment: From which controller do you want to show (push) this new view controller (do want to be able to push it from any controller that's on the screen when the notification comes in)? What is the purpose of this new controller? Depending on what it's for, a modal presentation might be more appropriate.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, I want to push an existing view controller (from my storyboard) onto any controller that is displayed at that point in time. I mean that would be the perfect solution for me. Is that possible? As I've said, bringing up a view modally is my last resort

Comment: @SergeyCatraniuc, why is bringing it up modally your last resort? If you want to be able to present it from any controller, I'm not sure you have any choice. Since information coming in from a push notification is an interruption to the app logic flow, a modal presentation seems most appropriate -- that's what they're for.

Comment: @rdelmar Yeah I understand that modal presentation is logical here. I just wanted an experience like in the Messages.app, where you would open the app when a notification comes and it will open right on the controller with the conversation and the option to tap Back and go to the full message list. I guess I'll have to go with a modal presentation. I just thought that maybe there should be some way to tell the Storyboard to jump to a particular view, that would be the awesomest thing to come from StoryBoards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I guess I don't give up that easily :) Here's the solution I found to my problem. Since I am presenting my main app views from within a modal view controller, here's what I did:

Since iOS 5 every view controller has a `presentedViewController` property. Once you know that, it's pretty easy from there.
Here's some specific code from inside AppDelegate.m

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {  
   if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"notificationType"] isEqualToString: @"messageType"])   {

   UITabBarController * tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController];
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:kChatViewIndex]; 
// My view controller that I presented modally is a tabBar, your case can be different. 

// ... so from here I can reach any navigation controller or any other view from inside my app

}
```

Now since you've got your view controller, you can use setSelectedIndex: if it's a tabBarController, or push a certain view controller if it's a navigation unit.

Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.
Cheers!